# How to make a constraint on the parameters of the constructor

Tags: c++

Now I am trying to design a class for a deck of cards.
I have:
Card.h

```
class Card {
public:
    enum Suit { CLUBS = 1, SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, RED_JOKER, BLACK_JOKER };
    Card(int card, Suit suit);

private:
    int _card;
    Suit _suit;
};
```

For the constructor with parameters, I am going to make a constraint on card, the range of it is 1 to 13，so I am going to write the constructor like this:

```
Card::Card(int card, Suit suit) throw (int) {
    if (card < 1 || card > 13) {
        delete this;
        throw card;
    }
}
```

I don't think the way I write the constructor is elegant.
I also consider to add an enum for card. But it just works for this question.
What about if I need to check a value from 1 to 100000?
Could anyone give some suggestion?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good idea to check the values during construction, but you should **not** call `delete` on `this`. The system will make sure that if memory was allocated for the object it is released when the exception propagates.

A better implementation (in my opinion) would be:

```
Card::Card(int card, Suit suit) {
    if (card < 1 || card > 13) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Invalid card value" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick- exception specifiers have been deprecated (except `noexcept`)

Comment: @luke: I did not even realized. I copied the constructor from the question and then modified. You are right in that exception specifiers make little to no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make your Card number as an enum instead of a int. This makes error is reported in the compiling time

Comment: I think it is a good idea for class Card, too. I just hope to know a general method to do do the validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reason to believe the constructor might in any (exceptional or not) real use scenario be called with a value outside the range? It seems unlikely to me, so I'd rather specify its behaviour for such input as undefined and don't throw any exceptions at all. While in development, you can add a good old `assert`, which is rather more useful for debug purposes since it immediately tells the location of the problem and leaves, allowing to produce a straightforward core dump.

```
#include <cassert>

Card::Card(int card, Suit suit) {
  assert(card >= 1 && card <= 13);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want my program abort.